# symfony2 translating errormessages

Tags: validation, symfony, translation

I want to translate errormessages inside validation.yml.

If I have a normal "NotBlank" rule, it works like following:

```
- NotBlank: { message: not.blank.firstname }
```

But what if there are some further rules like:

```
        - NotBlank: { message: not.blank.username }
        - Length:
            min: 7
            max: 50         
            minMessage: "Your Username must be at least {{ limit }} characters length"
```

This works, but how should I handle the minMessage? Also for the reason that I want to give USers some hints about the min Length of the input.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
- NotBlank: { message: not.blank.username }
- Length:
    min: 7
    max: 50
    minMessage: 'username.minLength'
    maxMessage: 'username.maxLength'
```

Your **validators.LANG.yml**:

```
username:
    minLength: "Your Username must be at least 7 characters length"
    maxLength: "Your Username must be at least 50 characters length"
```